# storing images in phone memory using picasso or universal image loader instead of cache

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader, picasso

i am using using picasso library for loading images from url and the images are loading perfectly but the problem is it stores the images on cache memory of device and after loading many images it runs out of memory so is their any way to store images  on phone memory , the images downloaded should be shored as **APP DATA** of the application so that when device is disconnected from the net it still can  fetch the image.

---

If its not posssible to store images on device using picasso  the how can we achive the same using  universal image loader , i wanted to know the UIL option configuration.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Storing of Image using picasso we can achieve.

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(mUrl).into(target);
private Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    }
}
```

Write ur logic in onBitmapLoaded to store images into disk.

Check [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation) it may help you, where it does everything for you.

Comment: i am  using Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(mUrl).into(ivmageview); which loads the image in imageview and saves a copy in cache but i want it to save the copy into my disk instead of cache. is their any method like  Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(mUrl).into(ivmageview).cachelocation(disk);

Comment: Use the given appraoch, where after on bitmap download, you can write code to save the image in sdcard.

Comment: i can store the images on sd card  but  picasso wont be having any information of that images so im future when i use picasso.load it will only chech its directory and if images are not store their they will be downloaded again instead of using from the sdcard